# java Spring Jet Brains Idea autowired sessionFactory inspection

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-annotations

Hello stackoverflow community. Have some problem with my project Spring Maven Hib Gwt. I have all inspections enabled in Idea and when I'm autowiring session factory this way in my class

```
 package com.somepackage.server.service;

@Service("someService")
public class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass

@Autowired   
private  SessionFactory sessionFactory; // checks autowiring problem in a bean clacc
```

I have an inspection problem. "Could not autowire. No beans of 'SessionFactory' type found". When Iam adding Qualifier got no inspection message

```
@Service("someService")
public class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass

@Autowired 
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")  
private  SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

All works fine and I can navigate to dependecies. I believe the problem is with my sonfig files, not with Idea itself. Here is my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.somepackages"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/db.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan"
              value="com.somepackages"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">${hibernate.connection.useUnicode}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">${hibernate.connection.characterEncoding}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">${hibernate.connection.charSet}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Ones again Everything works just fine, but this inspection problem makes me mad. Any Help ? THX

Comment: just set inspection level of `spring bean autowiring` to a lower level.

Comment: Yes but why it appears? I only work with spring for last 4 month and cannot figure the problem myself

Comment: This is only a configuration problem with your intelliJ, the info you given is not enough.

Comment: Problem with Idea inspection settings? Then why it works just fine with @Qualifier annotation? I'm using Idea 13.1.1U. All inspections on max. FindBugs cant find any problem. What info I should  also to provide, maven pom.xml?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I fixed it with the @Qualifier annotation like you did. But yeah I would like to know why this is happening with only that LocalSessionFactoryBean...

Answer (score 2):

The inspection is telling you the truth, inasmuch as your `sessionFactory` bean is not actually of type `SessionFactory.`

Your `sessionFactory` bean is *actually* of type `LocalSessionFactoryBean` which is a factory object that *manufactures* a configured `SessionFactory` instance.

Presumably IDEA behaves the same with other `FactoryBean` implementations as well.

Comment: Yes your are right, but how to fix then? org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 contains only LocalSession or SessionFactoryUtils when org.hiberante contains only SessionFactory, no LocalSession and etc. THX

Answer (score 1):

Yes probably this is where the problem is. 
 \webapp\WEB-INF\applicationContext.xml
and in idea Project Settings > Module > Spring i delete facet 'Spring' applicationContext I got  no warning after this action, about bean autowire, but receiveng "Spring Configuration Check" issue. Looks like the problem somewhere here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression in Intellij 13.1. I reverted to Intellij 13.0.3

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Previous+IntelliJ+IDEA+Releases

and the ide is happy again with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. Do this:
If you are using a config.java file then follow option 1

Option 1
- Hit F4 to open project settings.
- Click on Spring facets
[image]

- Click '+' and add your Config.java file in the facet list and any other beans.xml that you are using. 
  [image]

Option 2- If you are using spring-config.xml for configuration
- Hit F4 to open project settings.
- Click on Spring facets
[image]

- Click '+' and add your spring-xx xmls file in the facet list and any other beans.xml that you are using. 
  [image]